# How to migrate from NeoBundle to Dein?

Tags: plugin-system, plugin-neobundle

Shougo is no longer maintaining NeoBundle, but instead has re-written a plugin manager from scratch under the name `Dein`.

The [Dein GitHub page](https://github.com/Shougo/dein.vim) says:

> - No Vundle/NeoBundle compatibility

Given that NeoBundle is no longer actively developed, how does one migrate from NeoBundle to Dein?

Comment: apart from not being maintained, is there anything that doesn't work for you?

Comment: No, but I might as well accept the inevitable, and gain the improvements.

Comment: If your plugin manager works, has no bug and doesn't lack a feature you need there is no real reason to change it. Now if you really want to change the migration will depend on what you do with NeoBundle: you simply install some plugins simply follow the readme and create your `call dein#add()` calls. If you use some more specific hooks you'll have to put them in your question otherwise people on here won't be more helpful than a good reading of the doc.